# Jquery - Open with specific rel link clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a really simple jQuery snippet that is fading in content when a specific link is clicked...

http://jsbin.com/ijuveh/1/edit

What I am trying to do now is set it so that I can visit the page at www.mydomain.com/page.php#link2

and have the page.php open with #link2 already clicked.

How would I approach this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add names to the `a`'s:

```
<a href="#" rel="div_1" id="link1">Link 1</a>
```

And a code that first get the name after `#` on the url, and then open the corresponding element with `click()`.

```
var link=document.location.hash;
if (link) {
    var el = $(link);
    if (el) el.click();
}
```

Sample: http://jsbin.com/ONiWURI/2#link1

Source: http://jsbin.com/ONiWURI/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

catch the hash code, select the element per hashcode(=id of element) and fade it in
(on dom-ready):
`var hash   = document.location.hash; $('#'+hash).fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut();`